# vmware-clarity - How to get the clarity dropdown open/close state to toggle the caret up/down icon?

Tags: vmware-clarity

How to get the clarity drop down open or close state to toggle the caret up or down icon?

[dropdowns](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/dropdowns)

Comment: I'm sorry, can you try to rephrase your question with more detail? Its not clear what you're asking.

Comment: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/dropdowns

dropdown caret icon is not changing when it is in open state.

Answer (score 0):

This is not done intentionally, though you can do it yourself fairly easily by wrapping the template with a two-way binding like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" clrDropdownTrigger>
    Dropdown
    <clr-icon shape="caret down" *ngIf="!buttonOpen"></clr-icon>
    <clr-icon shape="caret up" *ngIf="buttonOpen"></clr-icon>
</button>
<ng-template [(clrIfOpen)]="buttonOpen">
<clr-dropdown-menu>
...
</clr-dropdown-menu>
</ng-template>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-icurbz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html